# Lazy-initialization enabled CardLayout?

Tags: java, swing, lazy-initialization, cardlayout

I have a bunch of panels put in a `CardLayout` where n<sup>th</sup> panel depends on the state changes caused in (n - 1)<sup>th</sup> panel. Since with `CardLayout`, you have to *initialize and* add all panels beforehand. As such it makes it harder than necessary to manage state.

Does Java or some third party open source library provide a variation of `CardLayout` that initializes its constituent panels lazily i.e. they are initialized just before they are going to be visible?

**Edit:**

Perhaps I did not state the problem clearly. Let me try again.

I *need* to set up the panels in `CardLayout` beforehand, but I do not want it to initialize them until they are to be made visible. This is necessary so that the state changes from previous stages are transparently propagated to next stages.

In my current code, I have:

```
cardsPanel.add(ReadMePanel.create(this), ReadMePanel.ID);
cardsPanel.add(LicencePanel.create(this), LicencePanel.ID);
cardsPanel.add(InstallationPathPanel.create(this), InstallationPathPanel.ID);
cardsPanel.add(
  ExtractionProgressPanel.create(
    this,
    new NormalizedPath(appContext.getParameter("zipFilePath")),
    new NormalizedPath(appContext.getInstallationDirectory().toString())
  ), 
  ExtractionProgressPanel.ID
);
```

Here `InstallationPathPanel` allows users to select a different installation directory than the default one. `ExtractionProgressPanel` is supposed to extract a certain zip file to this directory. if `ExtractionProgressPanel` were lazily initialized, the user selected path would be propagated to it, without me doing anything extra.

Hope the problem is clear now.

Comment: "Since with `CardLayout`, you have to initialize and add *all* panels beforehand."  Who said so?

Comment: I strongly second what Andrew states above. There is no such requirement when using CardLayout.

Comment: Sorry for mis-stating the problem. Point of emphasis changed. Hope that clarifies it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize and add the panel to the `CardLayout` right before calling the `show` method, so there is no problem.

*EDIT*

So on the location where you now call `CardLayout#show`, you could first do an `add` and then the `show`

As it looks like you are trying to create a wizard, the [following article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/swing/wizard/) might be a good place to start

Comment: @missingfaktor I see your edit, and still do not see why you could not use this solution.

Comment: I never call `CardLayout#show`. I have a panel with `CardLayout` as its `LayoutManager`.

Comment: Also the essence of question is reducing or if possible avoiding the bookkeeping I am having to do with the current approach.

Comment: @missingfaktor Sounds like you want to create a wizard. Perhaps [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/swing/wizard/) is helpful

Comment: @mKorbel, I am not really up for that. Time constraints... sorry.

Comment: The article proved to be quite useful. I refactored my code in accordance with the design described in the post, and that solved the problem I was facing earlier (the one described in my question.) If you include the link to this article in your answer, I will mark it as correct.